# Excel 2010 Run-Time error '91'

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to run a macro. We will call this workbook A. The macro opens up a file menu to select another workbook, lets call this workbook B. The macro then  opens up 5 other workbooks and pulls information from other excel files into Workbook B.

This worked just fine two months ago now I keep getting `Run-Time error '91'` Where I am having the problem at is

`Cells.Find(What:=sFindString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate`

and

`Cells.Find(What:=sFindString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate`

My code is below:

```
Public Sub Main(sPath, sFile)
Dim CR, LR As Integer, sAB_Bal, sABClos, sABComp, sABOpen, sAP_Bal, sAPClos, sAPComp, sAPOpen, sCol, sCol_OC, sFileBank, sFileGIT, sMD, sMN, sPathGIT As String
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, FileItem As Scripting.File
Application.DefaultFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"                 'SET DEFAULT FILE PATH AND PROMPT TO OPEN THE GOAL AND INCENTIVE TRACKER FILE
Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject: Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\")
sPathGIT = Application.GetOpenFilename("Worksheets (*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb; *.xls), *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb; *.xls", , "PLEASE SELECT THE G.I.T. FILE:")
If StrComp(sPathGIT, "False") = 0 Then
    iYesNo = MsgBox("You clicked Cancel.  Do you wish to exit?", vbYesNo, "EXIT?")
    If iYesNo = 6 Then
        GoTo Q1
    ElseIf iYesNo = 7 Then
        MsgBox ("You must re-open this file to be prompted for the G.I.T. file again."): Exit Sub
    End If
End If
MonthPrompt.Show                                                        'PROMPT FOR THE REPORT MONTH & YEAR
If MonthPrompt.ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString And MonthPrompt.ComboBox2.Value = vbNullString Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Application.Quit
End If                                                                  'PROMPT FOR THE GIT FILE NAME & OPEN
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled                                'PREVENT RANDOM LINE BY LINE VBA BREAK ISSUE
Application.ScreenUpdating = True: DoEvents: MsgBox ("First click OK to begin verifying each bank's file." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "(part 1 of 2...progress bar will display)")
ProgressBar.Caption = "PROCESSING - PLEASE WAIT...": DoEvents: ProgressBar.Percentage.Width = 0: Call ShowProgress(0.01): DoEvents
Workbooks.Open Filename:=sPathGIT: sFileGIT = Replace(sPathGIT, sPath, vbNullString)
sMN = MonthPrompt.ComboBox1.Value                                       'CURRENT MONTH NAME & DATE (ROW BELOW)
sMD = Month(MonthPrompt.ComboBox1.Value & "/1/" & MonthPrompt.ComboBox2.Value) & "/1/" & MonthPrompt.ComboBox2.Value
Sheets(8).Select: Call VerifyNoDup(sAB_Bal): sCol = CLet(sMD)                       'Business DDA Average Balance
Sheets(5).Select: Call VerifyNoDup(sABClos): If sCol <> CLet(sMD) Then GoTo E2      'Business DDA Closed
Sheets(4).Select: Call VerifyNoDup(sABOpen): If sCol <> CLet(sMD) Then GoTo E2      'Business DDA Openings
Sheets(6).Select: Call VerifyNoDup(sABComp): sCol_OC = CLet(sMD)                    'Business Open-Close
Sheets(7).Select: Call VerifyNoDup(sAP_Bal): If sCol <> CLet(sMD) Then GoTo E2      'Consumer DDA Average Balance
Sheets(2).Select: Call VerifyNoDup(sAPClos): If sCol <> CLet(sMD) Then GoTo E2      'Personal DDA Closed
Sheets(1).Select: Call VerifyNoDup(sAPOpen): If sCol <> CLet(sMD) Then GoTo E2      'Personal DDA Openings
Sheets(3).Select: Call VerifyNoDup(sAPComp): If sCol_OC <> CLet(sMD) Then GoTo E3   'Personal Open-Close
Windows(sFile).Activate: CR = 2: While StrComp(Range("C" & CR).Value, vbNullString) <> 0: CR = CR + 1: Wend: LR = CR: CR = 2
While CR < LR                                                           'CONFIRM ALL BANK FILES ARE PRESENT
    sFileBank = Range("C" & CR).Value
    If sFileBank <> Range("C" & CR - 1).Value Then
        If StrComp(Dir(sPath & sFileBank), vbNullString) = 0 Then GoTo E1
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=sPath & sFileBank: Windows(sFile).Activate
    End If: Call ShowProgress(CR / LR): DoEvents: CR = CR + 1
Wend: CR = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = True: DoEvents: MsgBox ("Now click OK to begin copying data." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "(part 2 of 2...progress bar will display)")
ProgressBar.Percentage.Width = 0: Call ShowProgress(0.01): DoEvents
While CR < LR                                                           'CONFIRM ALL BANK FILES HAVE REQUIRED WORKSHEETS AND FIELDS
    Call ShowProgress(CR / LR): DoEvents
    Call ScanImport(CR, LR, 0, sMN, sFileGIT, sFile, sABOpen, sCol, "raw data", "Business DDA")
    Call ScanImport(CR, LR, 1, sMN, sFileGIT, sFile, sABClos, sCol, "raw data", "Business DDA")
    Call ScanImport(CR, LR, 0, sMN, sFileGIT, sFile, sAB_Bal, sCol, "raw data 3", "Business DDA")
    Call ScanImport(CR, LR, 0, sMN, sFileGIT, sFile, sABComp, sCol_OC, sCol, "Business DDA")    'FILL FORMULAS FOR BUSINESS OPEN-CLOSE
    Call ScanImport(CR, LR, 0, sMN, sFileGIT, sFile, sAPOpen, sCol, "raw data", "Personal DDA")
    Call ScanImport(CR, LR, 1, sMN, sFileGIT, sFile, sAPClos, sCol, "raw data", "Personal DDA")
    Call ScanImport(CR, LR, 0, sMN, sFileGIT, sFile, sAP_Bal, sCol, "raw data 3", "Personal DDA")
    Call ScanImport(CR, LR, 0, sMN, sFileGIT, sFile, sAPComp, sCol_OC, sCol, "Personal DDA")    'FILL FORMULAS FOR PERSONAL OPEN-CLOSE
    Call ShowProgress(CR / LR): DoEvents: CR = CR + 1
Wend: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Windows(sFile).Close: Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Exit Sub
E1: MsgBox ("You are missing the following required bank file:" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & sFileBank): GoTo Q1
E2: MsgBox ("The column for month '" & sMD & "' appears inconsisent among the Business & Personal 'Open' or 'Closed' worksheets."): GoTo Q1
E3: MsgBox ("The column for month '" & sMD & "' appears inconsistent between the Business & Personal 'Open-Close' ratio worksheets."): GoTo Q1
Q1: Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Application.Quit
End Sub

Public Function CLet(sFindString) As String                                'RETURN COLUMN LETTER
    Cells.Find(What:=sFindString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
CLet = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, InStr(ActiveCell.Address, "$") + 1, InStr(2, ActiveCell.Address, "$") - 2)
End Function

Public Function RNum(sFindString) As Integer                                'RETURN ROW NUMBER
Cells.Find(What:=sFindString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
RNum = ActiveCell.Row
End Function
```

Comment: What is the value of your variable sFindString?

Comment: The value is selected in the Macro... There is a Month/Year picker.. Right now Im picking February 2013 which would be 2/1/2013 for sFindString

Comment: As far as I know error 91 occurs when it can't find the value you are searching for. Is '2/1/2013' definitely in the sheets you are searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below changes.

```
 Public Function CLet(sFindString) As String                                'RETURN COLUMN LETTER
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=sFindString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Activate
            CLet = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, InStr(ActiveCell.Address, "$") + 1, InStr(2, ActiveCell.Address, "$") - 2)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function RNum(sFindString) As Integer                                'RETURN ROW NUMBER
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=sFindString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Activate
            RNum = ActiveCell.Row
        End If
    End Function
```